# Mutiple messages after leaving and rejoining Socket.io room

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am having the user join a room when a React component mounts and then leave the room when it un-mounts. After leaving then rejoining a room, the user gets two messages. Then 3 on the following attempt and so on. I am using the same socket throughout the transactions. (Or at least think I am)

I tried not joining both rooms and not leaving right at the user connects and the same issue still occurs.

```js
// Server side - App.js
// Required Express, http server, and socket.io
require('./middleware/socket')(io);
```

```js
// socket.js
module.exports = io => {
    io.on('connection', socket => {
        socket.on('join', data => {
            socket.join(data.room);
        });
        socket.on('leave', data => {
            socket.leave(data.room);
        });

        socket.on('event', data => {
            socket.in('event').emit('event', {username: data.username, msg: data.msg});
        });
        socket.on('package', data => {
            socket.in('package').emit('package', {username: data.username, msg: data.msg});
        });
    });
}
```

```js
// Client Side index.js
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
// Pass Socket to Child Component - event.js
<Switch>
...
<Route exact path="/event">
  <Event 
    endpoint={this.state.endpoint}
    username={name}
    _event={this.state.package}
    socket={socket}
/>
</Route>
</Switch>
```

```js
// event.js
componentDidMount = () => {
        this.props.socket.emit('join', {room: 'event'});
        this.props.socket.on('event', data => {
            document.querySelector('.posts').innerHTML += `${data.username} said: ${data.msg}<br/>`;
        });
    }
componentWillUnmount = () => {
        this.props.socket.emit('leave', {room: 'event'});
    }
```

I expected the user to leave the room and when they rejoin, only get one message.